# values reset with rotation Mainactivity

Tags: java, android

I started the Android language Studio and I only need one step to finish this first TD.

Here are the instructions from TD:

In MainActivity, create an array of Boolean values
mQuestionTrichee, to browse with variable mIndexActuel

ok, so here that's I did:

```
private static final String A_TRICHE = "a triche";
private boolean[] mQuestionTrichee = new boolean[mTabQuestions.length];
```

After, I have the value of Question Cheat [mIndexActuel] in the Bundle in the onSaveInstanceState () method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mIndexActuel);
    outState.putBoolean(A_TRICHE, mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel]);
}
```

So, then, I have to get its value in onCreate ():

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate appelee");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel]=savedInstanceState.getBoolean(A_TRICHE);

 }
```

but I have this error later:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I tried to browse my table in the method onCreate () or onSaveInstanceState () but nothing changed I still have it.

Here's what I added:

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YARvD.png)

```
   if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        for(mIndexActuel=0; mIndexActuel < mTabQuestions.length; mIndexActuel++)
        {
            if(mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel]==true)
            {
                mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel] = false;
            }
        }
        mIndexActuel = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX,0);
        mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel] = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(A_TRICHE);
    }
```

Comment: I'll give you a hand but post the `bundle.getBoolean()` which is in the `onCreate()` code first :)

Comment: Please post by editing the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: I see where your problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }` you need to do a null check:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel] = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(A_TRICHE);
    }
}
```

The bundle savedInstanceState will be null if the state of the app has not previously been saved.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help, already my application starts.        
I just have one last problem, when I click on help normally the following message is displayed "You are a cheater" but when I turn the tablet the user can answer again, here is my real problem ..
I think that it could come from the loop because of 1 I do not know or the declared is 2 I do not know if it is correct or not ..

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onCreate()`, the part where you're trying to get the boolean from `savedInstanceState`, you're getting a `NullPointerException` since in `onCreate()` sometimes the value of `savedInstanceState` returned is null. 
What you can do is either put an `if` condition before the line `savedInstanceState.getBoolean(A_TRICHE)` or override the `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method and place that line there which is also a better practice.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this -

```
if( savedInstanceState != null){
    mQuestionTrichee[mIndexActuel] = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(A_TRICHE);
}
```

You need to check if the savedInstanceState only then try to get the value.

Comment: Your answer is just copypaste of @androidas and also you haven't explained our answer.Between I haven't voted you down :) .